# Broken code with roles in GHC 7.8

Tags: haskell, ghc

Some of my code is broken with the newest version of ghc 7.8.2.

I'm using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to deriving instances of `Data.Vector.Unbox` using the following:

```
data VoxelPos     = VoxelPos
                    {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
                    {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
                    {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
                  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

newtype FacePos = FacePos VoxelPos deriving ( Eq, Hashable, NFData, G.Vector U.Vector, M.MVector U.MVector, U.Unbox)
```

where `VoxelPos` have manual rolled instances using `(Int, Int, Int)`:

```
newtype instance U.MVector s VoxelPos = MV_VoxelPos (U.MVector s (Int, Int, Int))
newtype instance U.Vector    VoxelPos = V_VoxelPos  (U.Vector    (Int, Int, Int))
instance U.Unbox VoxelPos
instance M.MVector U.MVector VoxelPos where
  basicLength (MV_VoxelPos v) ...
  ...
```

and this was working with the previous versions of ghc. But after upgrading ghc, I get the following error:

```
Could not coerce from ‘U.MVector s (Int, Int, Int)’ to ‘U.MVector
                                                              s FacePos’
      because the second type argument of ‘U.MVector’ has role Nominal,
      but the arguments ‘(Int, Int, Int)’ and ‘FacePos’ differ
      arising from the coercion of the method ‘M.basicLength’ from type
                   ‘forall s. U.MVector s VoxelPos -> Int’ to type
                   ‘forall s. U.MVector s FacePos -> Int’
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (M.MVector U.MVector FacePos)
```

which, I think, is because of addition of roles. I know that roles improves safety when using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` which is, of course, really good!

What are the possible solutions to solve this? And what is the most recommended one?

Comment: According to the docs (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/roles.html) , you have to change the role of the datatype, but this can only be done at the definition of the datatype, I believe. I'm not sure how roles interact with data families - maybe you can define roles on a per-instance basis - but I doubt it.

Comment: But to change the role of `MVector` I should change it on the `vector` library. Maybe I should report it to the maintainer of the `vector` package.

Answer (score 2):

Having an error here is sensible -- it's possible that the `U.MVector` instance for `FacePos` is utterly unrelated to the instance for `VoxelPos`. There's a nice way to fix this, though:

```
newtype instance U.MVector s FacePos = MV_FacePos (U.MVector s VoxelPos)
```

That should get rid of the particular error you're seeing.

However, I think you'll hit another role-related error right away, because other functions (not `basicLength`, where you're snagged) use the `MVector` parameters in a way roles can't currently deal with.

The GHC team is aware of this problem and is working on it: see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9112 and https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9123

In the meantime, I'm afraid my only suggestion is to use `unsafeCoerce`. :(

Comment: Thanks for answering this. Could you explain how we could use `unsafeCoerce` to solve this problem?